# php socket connections

Tags: php, sockets

i'm trying to make a php tcp/ip server with the following code:

```
<?php 
// set some variables 
$host = "localhost"; 
$port = 3804; 

// don't timeout! 
set_time_limit(0); 

// create socket 
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

// bind socket to port 
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n"); 

// start listening for connections 
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n"); 

// accept incoming connections 
// spawn another socket to handle communication 
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");

// read client input 
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");

// clean up input string 
$input = trim($input); 

// reverse client input and send back
$output = strrev($input) .   "\n"; 
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n"); 

// close sockets 
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket); 
?>
```

i've randomly choose to work on the 3804 port and when i'm trying to telnet to my host on that port i'm not able to make a connection.. is there any more settings i need to make in the server that the php scripts hosted in, in order to allow my php script to listen to that port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you pass `"localhost"` as the second parameter of [`socket_bind`](http://php.net/socket_bind), your socket will only listen to connections from the address `localhost` resolves to, typically 127.0.0.1. Set `$host = '0.0.0.0';` to allow connections from everywhere.

You may also want to configure your firewall(s) to let through connections to port 3804.

Comment: i've changed the localhost to my real ip.
i'm not the administrator of the server.. its a unix server and i've looked in the /etc/services file and i saw that port 50000 is not register on anything.. i've tried it and still nothing.. what can i try more ? or what setting should i do in the server ?

Comment: Well, what error do you get? Without the exact error (and possibly a packet dump), it's impossible to pinpoint the problem. Both 3804 and 50000 are unregistered, but there's nothing that forbids you to pick a registered port, it's just convention.

Comment: the error is: could not open port to host, on port 50000: Connect faild

Comment: This indicates either a firewall, or a mistaken address. If you can make sure that the address you use on the client matches your server's , execute `netstat -ltpn | grep 50000` on your server. If that outputs something (i.e. php is running on the port), contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

That code works for me. Are you running this code from apache or another web server? Have you tried running those lines with `php -a`?

Comment: i've run from another web server. i've tried both -a and -q..
i think its something with the server..